# how to extract text from inside quotes using findstr

Tags: windows, batch-file, findstr

I have a directory full of files I am trying to findstr and extract whats inside the quotes

my test

```
G:\Games\Steam\steamapps\common\XXXXXXXXX\addons>findstr addontitle workshop\*.vpk
workshop\XXXXXXXXX.vpk:        addontitle "Addon 1"
workshop\XXXXXXXX.vpk:        addontitle                      "Addon 2"
-cont-
```

I just want to have the title only

```
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=:^" %%i in ('findstr /RC:"addontitle *\".*\"" "workshop\*.vpk"') do (
    echo "FOUND: %%~ni.vpk TITLE: %%k"
    mkdir "custom\%%~ni">nul 2>&1
    mklink ".\custom\%%~ni\pak01_dir.vpk" "..\..\workshop\%%~ni.vpk">nul 2>&1
    echo            Game                "left4dead2\addons\custom\%%~ni"        // %%k>> %GAMEINFO%
)

for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=:^" %%i in ('findstr /VRC:"addontitle *\".*\"" "workshop\*.vpk"') do (
    echo "FOUND: %%~ni.vpk"
    mkdir "custom\%%~ni">nul 2>&1
    mklink ".\custom\%%~ni\pak01_dir.vpk" "..\..\workshop\%%~ni.vpk">nul 2>&1
    echo            Game                "left4dead2\addons\custom\%%~ni"        // ADDON INFO MISSING>> output.txt
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace double quotes in findstr batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728577/how-to-replace-double-quotes-in-findstr-batch-file)

Comment: @T3RR0R I think using `repl.bat` is a bit extreme for a case like this where there seems to be only one quoted substring in the file.

Comment: the solution worked great thanks a huge ton im kinda curious if its possible to see which vpk DID NOT match the string so I can add them in to output.txt by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=:^" %%i in ('findstr /RC:"addontitle *\".*\"" "workshop\*.vpk"') do (
    mkdir "custom\%%~ni">nul 2>&1
    mklink ".\custom\%%~ni\pak01_dir.vpk" "..\..\workshop\%%~ni.vpk">nul 2>&1
    echo          Game                "XXXXXXXX\addons\custom\%%~ni"        // %%k
)>> output.txt
```

`findstr` gets the name of the file anyway when used on list of files, so just use that.

**Note** I took the liberty of adding double quotes to the string `echo`ed `"XXXXXXXX\addons\custom\%%~ni"` if you do not need it, just remove it.

In the event that `addontitle` can be in any case, add `/I` to the `findstr` command.

```
@echo off
for /f tokens^=1-3delims^=:^" %%i in ('findstr /IRC:"addontitle *\".*\"" "workshop\*.vpk"') do (
    mkdir "custom\%%~ni">nul 2>&1
    mklink ".\custom\%%~ni\pak01_dir.vpk" "..\..\workshop\%%~ni.vpk">nul 2>&1
    echo          Game                "XXXXXXXX\addons\custom\%%~ni"        // %%k
)>> output.txt
```